# Problem on boot - "Missing modules ALERT! UUID does not exist - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, hard-drive

if someone knows how to solve this issue it would be wonderful.

**Problem:** Blocked in BusyBox in the booting process. I can’t access to my root location to follow these instructions (https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=47594).

**Error:**

“Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)

Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

ALERT! UUID=[…] does not exist. Dropping a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.4) build-in shell (ash)

(initramfs) _”

- ‘blkid’ shows nothing.
- ‘ls /dev/’ does not show “sda” type of file…

**Things tried:** locate the root using a USB Drive

**Origin:** apt update + upgrade showed black screen, tried to resolve that and this is where I am.

If someone have an idea, do not hesitate to reply! If not, it is possible for me to save the data from this computer? If so, how?

Comment: Not really, in my case the command "ls -latr /dev/disk/by-uuid/" done by a USB stick shows nothing except the USB drive itself. It looks like my internal SSD isn't detected..